# Once the website is opened. DO NOT move focus outside the tab/window

Tags: tabs, window, focus

1. I am trying to start a online quiz website.
2. If the user entered the quiz page. He should not be able to search on the other tab or other window.
3. This gives the genuine answer without coping.
4. If there is a chance to include any of web based codes for this website give me the best answer with the right code.

Comment: Put some code what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a huge security risk if you could control/know what people are doing in other tabs of their browser; therefore, it is obviously not allowed. You cannot prevent a user from using other tabs within their browser; and you have absolutely no control over what they can do outside of your site.

Comment: I found this facility on http://ranksheet.com/.
please help me as fast as you can

Comment: How did they prevent you from opening another browser window? I dont think you are providing enough information because as far as I know this is impossible.